# plotly - embed SoundCloud icon

Tags: soundcloud, plotly

I am developing an App in plotly (https://plot.ly) using data from SoundCloud API. I would like to add a SoundCloud icon to my interactive plotly graph to point people to a particular SoundCloud page (plotly installation instructions can be found here: https://plot.ly/r/getting-started/)

Note that a hyperlink can be easily added to a plotly graph
(http://help.plot.ly/adding-HTML-and-links-to-charts/) with the following line of code:

```
<a href=”type URL here”>Type what you want user to see here </a>
```

Below is an example code for a SoundCloud icon, which can be embedded in a website: (https://soundcloud.com/pages/embed):

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/icon/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Frihanna&color=orange_white&size=32" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"></iframe>
```

Is it possible to embed this icon in a plotly graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, plotly currently only supports the following HTML tags:

- `sup`
- `sub`
- `b`
- `i`
- `a`
- `span`
- `br`
- `em`

So, making that SoundCloud icon appear on a plotly graph is not possible at the moment.

That said, if you're willing to design a full-blown web page, you could easily make a plotly graph using [plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript/) and overlay it with the SoundCloud icon.

Comment: Good to know regarding plotly.js, will have a look. Thanks a lot!